# GWT Cell Widgets and double click behaviour

Tags: gwt, click, cell, double-click

I have a Cell that handles both "click" and "dblclick".
One behaviour for click, different behaviour for dblclick.

When double click on the cell it fires 3 events.

click, click, and dblclick.

Is there a way to filter the "click" events?

As an example:

```
...
public TestCell(EventBus eventBus){
        super("click","keydown", "dblclick");
}

...

public onBrowserEvent( ... ){
   String eventType = event.getType();
   if("click".equals(eventType)){
     //do smthg.
   }
   if("dblclick".equals(eventType)){
     //do smthg different.
   }
}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: This is normal. You have to filter based on the number of clicks. Can you post the code where you handle click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...and if you didn't want to handle `dblclick`, you wouldn't understand why GWT/the browser gives you only only one click out of 2…

As @adel-boutros said, this is just how it's supposed to work, and you have to live with it.

Check the `event.detail` for the number of clicks. Unfortunately, you'll have to use JSNI, as GWT doesn't seem to expose the field in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int clickCount = 0;

public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) { 
  switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) { 
    case Event.ONCLICK: 
      clickCount++; 
      if (clickCount == 1) {
        Timer timer = new Timer() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            onClickAction();
          }
        }
        timer.schedule(200);
      }
      break; 

    case Event.ONDBLCLICK:   
      // your handler code here     
      break;
  }
} 

private void onClickAction() {
  if (clickCount == 1) {
    // Do single click actions
  } // If clickCount > 1, don't perform single click operation.
  clickCount = 0;
}
```

Case Single Click:

```
  1. click -> clickCount = 1.
  2. set timer to fire onClick action after 200ms.
  3. 200ms elapse, onClickAction() fires.
  4. clickCount = 1, perform single click actions.
  5. reset clickCount = 0.
```

Case Double Click

```
  1. click -> clickCount = 1.
  2. set timer to fire onClick action after 200ms.
  3. click -> clickCount = 2. No timer set.
  4  200ms elapses from first click. Timer fires onClickAction.
  5. clickCount > 1, actions for single click not performed.
  6. reset clickCount = 0.
```